# Imprimir en Genexus 16 (java) con window.print();

Tags: javascript, genexus

tengo un problema al imprimir, me aparece la hoja blanca sin ningún texto al momento de llamar al window.print();

html es un textblock, esta con formato Raw HTML
&textohtml es de tipo longvanchar, va como parámetro con todo el código html que quiero que aparezca en el archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/*
Aparece la pantalla de imprimir pero vacío
*/ sin embargo al utilizar el mismo código en la evo 2 o evo 3 funciona sin problema

Si saben la solución me podrían ayudar

Gracias!!

Comment: En el web form del web panel que tiene ese código en el Start, ¿qué estás mostrando? window.print() debería imprimirte lo que se está viendo en la ventana actual

Comment: Buenas @GuidoLorenzatti si te referis a la variable &textohtml, ahi esta todo el texto en formato html que quiero mostrar en el web panel,
Si, deberia mostrar, pero por alguna razon no carga, es como si primero hiciera el window.print()

Comment: y al cerrar el window.print() añade lo de la variable

Comment: pero lo "solucione" de otra forma de momento